# OCaml: and keyword syntax error

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

I've written this mergesort implementation, which works fine if I put the divide function outside of the mergesort function. But when I try to make divide an inner function of mergesort I encounter a syntax error.

I know, there must be some really simple explanation for this. I've looked all over the internet, yet found nothing.

Here is the code:

```
let mergesort list = 
  let rec sort lists acc = (
    let rec merge sublist1 sublist2 merged_list =
    match sublist1 with
      |[] -> merged_list @ sublist2
      |hd1 :: tl1 -> 
        match sublist2 with
          |[] -> merged_list @ sublist1
          |hd2 :: tl2 -> 
            if hd1 < hd2 then merge tl1 sublist2 (merged_list @ hd1::[])
            else merge sublist1 tl2 (merged_list @ hd2::[])
    in match lists with 
      |[] -> 
        (match acc with
          |[] -> []
          |hd :: [] -> hd
          |_ -> sort acc [])
      |hd :: tl -> sort (List.tl tl) ((merge (List.hd tl) hd [])::acc)  
  )
  and rec divide list list_of_lists = (
    match list with
      [] -> list_of_lists
      |hd :: tl -> divide tl ((hd :: []) :: list_of_lists)
  )
  in sort (divide list []) []
;;
```

and it results into:

```
Characters 567-570:
and rec divide list list_of_lists = (
    ^^^
Error: Syntax error
```

Comment: Did you try removing the `rec` keyword that the error is telling you to? `and` will repeat the previous definition, which is in this case `let rec`, so you’re effectively writing `let rec rec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simply remove the `rec` keyword from your definition there.

This is because when you use the `and` keyword, you’re effectively repeating the previous definition syntactically, which in this case is `let rec`.

So your current implementation is effectively the same as saying `let rec rec`

Comment: when you're using the `and` keyword you're not repeating the previous definition.

Comment: @ivg then what is it doing exactly?

Comment: It is just a syntax (a notation) that separates multiple definitions. It is not really about the recursivity, e.g., `let x = y and y = x in expr` is not a recursive definition, and it binds two variables in `expr`. Cf., with `let x = y in let y = x in expr`

Answer (score 2):

A [local definition](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#s%3Alocaldef) has the following syntax in OCaml:

```
let [rec] pattern1 =  expr1 and … and  patternN =  exprN in expr
```

Thus an extra `rec` is not allowed after the `and` keyword, and is allowed only after the first `let`. The `rec` flag extends to all values defined in the local definition, thus you just need to remove this erroneous `rec` after `and`.